# Radio button always checked item show False

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor Radio buttons,But always checked item shows false.

### Code

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("NewsSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="card-body pt-5 flex-center flex-column">
                    <form class="form-checkout form-style-1">
                        <div class="form-group text-center mt-3 shipping-group">

                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x=>x.IsUseRegisteredAddress,true,new { @class = "custom-control-input", @checked = " " })

                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsUseRegisteredAddress, false, new { @class = "custom-control-input",@checked = " " })

                        </div>
                   </form>
                 </div>
           }
```

### Controller

```
Public ActionResult NewsSubmit(NewsTotal news)
{
return View();
}
```

### DTO

```
public class NewsTotal()
{
public bool IsUseRegisteredAddress{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: @JosueMartinez When i select the first radio button ,it's value is true..But it also shows me False

Answer (score 2):

The problem seem coming from declaration of your viewmodel property, which defined as `bool`, also you're not setting it from controller when received `NewsTotal` by using `return View(news)`:

```
public bool IsUseRegisteredAddress { get; set; }
```

Since default value of `bool` is `false` when not being set, then the radio button which has `false` value is checked by default. If you want to use `true` as default, you need to set it from controller action which returns view with viewmodel:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewsSubmit(NewsTotal news)
{    
    // set radio button state (optional, ignore this if it's already set in 'news' parameter)
    news.IsUseRegisteredAddress = true;

    // returning viewmodel is mandatory
    return View(news);
}
```

Or if you want to set all radio buttons unchecked by default, specify `Nullable<bool>` viewmodel property instead:

```
public bool? IsUseRegisteredAddress { get; set; }
```

**Notes:**

1) You might consider to remove `@checked` property from `RadioButtonFor` because `checked` is boolean property which represents checked state when the attribute is present (and unchecked while the attribute is not present), as provided below:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsUseRegisteredAddress, true, new { @class = "custom-control-input" }) Yes

@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsUseRegisteredAddress, false, new { @class = "custom-control-input" }) No
```

If the `checked` attribute present in two radio buttons with same name or group, the last radio button with `checked` attribute will be set as checked by default.

2) The second form `<form class="form-checkout form-style-1">` is not valid because it will create nested forms. Remove additional form tag inside `Html.BeginForm` helper and style the main form instead:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewsSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-checkout form-style-1" }))
{
    // form contents
}
```

Comment: There's a two radio buttons ,When i check the first one i need to set my property is True and when i click second one i need to set my property False

Comment: Consider looking for [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aiD3n3) - your problem is not just the property, it also has nested forms. Please remove the second `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

the right way to check your radio buttons is like this:

`@Html.RadioButtonFor(x=> x.IsUseRegisteredAddress, "Registered", new { @checked = true })`